# Having trouble deserializing multiple JSON variable

Tags: c#, json, api, serialization, get

I wrote the following code, it does deserialize and parse a single JSON variable, however, it won't work with multiple

The JSON retrieved by API has variables similar to the following, however, the first branch has a number that always changes, like value_abc_######, where ###### is a always different number, so I have no idea on what output I get for this one.

This is the JSON structure I get returned by the API call:

```
{
  "value_abc_154649": {
    "Name": "",
    "Address": "",
    "Phone": "",
  },
  "value_abc_616447": {
    "Name": "",
    "Address": "",
    "Phone": "",
  },
  "value_abc_912374": {
    "Name": "",
    "Address": "",
    "Phone": ""
  }
}
```

While this is the code I wrote, it works fine if the JSON has only 1 branch result, but with multiples it won't

```
    class getVariables
    {   
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    class fetch
    {
        var client = new System.Net.WebClient();
        string json = client.DownloadString(API_URL);
        var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<getVariables>(json);
        Console.Write("\nName: " + result.Name); //this just print an empty value

        /*I also tried this structure but the for loop doesn't work
        for (result)
        {
            Console.Write("\nName: " + result.Name);
        }*/
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You class does not represent your json structure. Try deserializing to `Dictionary<string, getVariables>`:

```
        var json = @"{
        ""value_abc_154649"": {
            ""Name"": """",
    ""Address"": """",
    ""Phone"": """",
  },
  ""value_abc_616447"": {
            ""Name"": """",
    ""Address"": """",
    ""Phone"": """",
  },
  ""value_abc_912374"": {
            ""Name"": """",
    ""Address"": """",
    ""Phone"": """"
  }
    }";

    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Dictionary<string, getVariables>>(json);
    // foreach(var r in result.Values)
    // {
    //    Console.Write("\nName: " + r.Name);
    //}
    // or to print with keys: 
    foreach(var kvp in result)
    {
        Console.WriteLine($"Key: {kvp.Key}, Name: {kvp.Value.Name}");
    }
```

Comment: Ok, I tried that, but the output just gives me: Exception: Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[System.String,API.API.getVariables]' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly.
To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) .....

Comment: .... or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List<T> that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array.
Path '', line 1, position 1.

Comment: @YoruTen you don't have any arrays (e.g. `[1,2,3]`) in example json in your question.

Comment: that is the identical JSON I get from the API call though

Comment: @YoruTen I've added full example with the json from your question, you can check it.

Answer (score 0):

You need the deserialize a list not a 1 element

```
var result=JsonConvert.Deserialize<List<getVariables>>(json);
```

After that you have your list